# Why get_absolute_url() isn't working

Tags: django, django-models

I'm a newbie in django and I have a problem with get_absolute_url():
My model:

```
class Band(models.Model):
B_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
Country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
imageband = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/band')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.B_Name

@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/genre/%s/%s/' % (self.B_Name, self.genre)
```

My url:

```
url(r'^genre/(\d+)/$', 'genre', name="genre"),  
url(r'^genre/(?P<B_Name>)/(?P<genre>\[-\w]+)/$', 'thu'),
```

My views:

```
def genre(request, url):
template = 'genre/genre.html'
if url=='1':
    tmp = Band.objects.raw('SELECT B_Name, Country FROM data_band WHERE genre_id=%s', ...)
if ....
......
return render_to_response(template,{'tmp':tmp})


def thu(request):
template = 'genre/thu.html'
tmp = Band.objects.raw('SELECT B_Name, genre FROM data_band')
return render_to_response(template,{'tmp':tmp})
```

My template genre.html:

```
{% for x in tmp %}
<tr>
<th><a href="{{x.get_absolute_url}}">{{x.B_Name}}</a></th>
<th>{{x.Country}}</th>
</tr>       
{% endfor %}
```

I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: What is the error or the url that isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [the Permalink decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator) your `get_absolute_url` method should return a tuple with view name, args and keyword args:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('genre', (), {       # 'genre' here is name of the url: name="genre"
        'B_Name': self.B_Name,   # substitute: (?P<B_Name>)
        'genre': self.genre.     # substitute:  (?P<genre>\[-\w]+)
    })
```

Comment: So probably there's sth wrong with the urls.py. In your urls you have `name="genre"` on the url without params. Try setting a name on the parametrized url too, and use that name it in get_absolute_url.

Comment: sorry, i fix it  @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('thu', (), {
            'B_Name': self.B_Name,
            'genre': self.Country})  and urls.py         url(r'^genre/(\d+)/$', 'genre', name="genre"), 
 url(r'^thu/(?P<B_Name>)/(?P<genre>\[-\w]+)/$', 'thu', name="thu"), it still not work

Answer (score 0):

Permalink takes either a view name or a url pattern name. In your case you have a view called 'genre' and a url pattern name called 'genre'. Which do you want to use?

It could be trying to match the first named url pattern and failing. Something to check at least.

Comment: i want to get view called 'thu' from template('genre.html') but it isn't working, maybe my urls.py is wrong

Comment: I can't see where you're calling the view named 'thu'. Maybe if you told us how it was going wrong... what's the error you're getting?

Comment: i think same as Secator, i'm thinking